# How to use python to stop reading code up to blank row without pandas, variable number of rows

Tags: python, excel, loops, csv, blender

Currently this code works well for one row, how would I get it to loop/repeat so that it can be done for a series of rows up to a blank row in the csv/excel format?

```
import csv

def read_csv(file_name='filepath.csv'):
    with open(file_name) as csv_file:
        file = csv.reader(csv_file)
        return [i for i in file]

csvFileArray = read_csv()
row = csvFileArray[1]  # first row
x, y, z, l, m, n, p, q, r = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8]

x = float(x)
y = float(y)
z = float(z)
l = float(l)
m = float(m)
n = float(n)
p = float(p)
q = float(q)
r = float(r)

y_axis = Vector((l, m, n))
z_axis = Vector((p, q, r))

x_axis = y_axis.cross(z_axis).normalized()

M = Matrix((x_axis, y_axis, z_axis)).transposed()

M = M.to_4x4()

M.translation = scale * Vector((x, y, z))

#test
print(M)
print(x_axis, y_axis, z_axis)
bpy.ops.object.empty_add()
mt = context.object
mt.empty_display_type = 'ARROWS'
mt.matrix_world = M
```

Tried while loop where: while x != 0 and y != 0 ...etc it doesn't seem to be working?

[system console message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPiYh.png)

[section of csv image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45H7l.png)

Comment: As a blank row doesn't have enough elements you can e. g. check the len of row and break from an infinite "while True" if too small.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? What are the 'commands' to check the row?

Comment: The csv.reader delivers each row as a list of strings. You just have to check the length of the list. Also you need a for-loop over the list of rows returned by "read_csv".

Comment: what is the csv data?? where does `Matrix`, `Vector`, `context`, `bpy` come from???

Comment: Its for use in blender

Comment: and the csv data?

Comment: csv data is simply coordinates and directional vectors, xyz are coordinates, lmn, pqr are direction vectors

Answer (score 0):

You first need to iterate over the data using a `for` loop.

Next check that the length of the row is `> 0`

You do not need to define each `row[i]`, only unpack the entire row ( a useful feature of python)

If you wish to end it at a blank row, uses break to end the loop.  The code will go there if it does not evaluate as `> 0`

```
csvFileArray = read_csv()
for row in csvFileArray[1:]: # iterate over the  row, ignore the first row (index 0) - start from index 1 -> last index
    if len(row) > 0:
        x, y, z, l, m, n, p, q, r = row # unpack the row - This is the same as x, y, z, l, m, n, p, q, r = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8]

        # Do calculations ... indent any logic involving the row items here.
        # from your code I would assume it is as follows:
        x = float(x)
        y = float(y)
        z = float(z)
        l = float(l)
        m = float(m)
        n = float(n)
        p = float(p)
        q = float(q)
        r = float(r)

        y_axis = Vector((l, m, n))
        z_axis = Vector((p, q, r))

        x_axis = y_axis.cross(z_axis).normalized()

        M = Matrix((x_axis, y_axis, z_axis)).transposed()

        M = M.to_4x4()

        M.translation = scale * Vector((x, y, z))

        #test
        print(M)
        print(x_axis, y_axis, z_axis)
        bpy.ops.object.empty_add()
        mt = context.object
        mt.empty_display_type = 'ARROWS'
        mt.matrix_world = M

    break # no need for an else clause but it is the same as having one.  This will stop the loop and end the routine.
```

Comment: I'm having indentation errors? The calculations are they supposed to be indented and also having errors with the break indentation- do I also keep this line: x, y, z, l, m, n, p, q, r = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8]

Comment: How would you skip the first row as that would contain text?

Comment: I'm getting a value error where it cant convert to float, I'm assuming  thats because the first row is x, y, z, dx, dy, dz..

Comment: You have not provided any information about the contents of the csv and there is no dx, dy, dz in the code specified..

Comment: So just the first row would need to be skipped, the dx,dy,dz are just names

Comment: to skip the first row use `for row in csvFileArray[1:]`  - i have updated the code

Comment: I seem to be getting an <unknown location>:-1 error for that line

Comment: Ok so I'm now not getting an error, but when I run it it appears to repeat the first row several times but not move on to the other rows

Comment: I am unable to see what you are looking at. please update your question or accept this one and create a new one!

Comment: I've added a couple of images from the system console and csv, it seems to only output the first row, same as before- it doesn't continue/loop through the rest of the rows

Comment: you need to add what imports you are using and a samp[le of the csv.. I have zero idea what you are doing..

Comment: It is for the software blender, creating an 'empty' object. What I wanted was for the code which worked row by row if you type in the row number to just loop/repeat the code so that I would only have to run it once and it would create these objects for every row up to the end of the data ie a blank row